Splitting Component logic into hooks
I am having a hard time coming up with a good approach for splitting business logic from a component. Due to different use cases, it has gotten too complicated and resulted in a long file. I've been attempting to split the logic in diferent hooks with the idea of activating each of them individually. I am worried that if I keep adding more hooks, I am  going to overload the App. These hooks have functionality that is causing frequent re-renders and other than passing flags to have them stop them from running to a certain extent, I cant think of a better way of doing this other than moving the hooks one level above which i wanted to avoid because i wanted to keep map logic within the map itself to avoid issues related to fetching google api data.
Is there a better way to structure the use of hooks while keeping them in the same place?
What i have is more or less like this. Data A and B represent different google map elements.
const App = ( {modality} ) => 
{ 
   const dataA = useHookA(); 
   const dataB = useHookB(); 

   let data;
    switch ( modality)
    {
      case 'A':
        data = dataA;
        break;
      case 'B':
        data = dataB;
        break;
     }

    return <GoogleMap>{data}</GoogleMap>
};


Instead of maintaining 2 logics, states, etc... when you only need one, create 2 map components, and switch between them:
const MapA = () => {
  const data = useHookA();
  
  return <GoogleMap>{data}</GoogleMap>
}

const MapB = () => {
  const data = useHookB();
  
  return <GoogleMap>{data}</GoogleMap>
}

const App = ({ modality }) => modality === 'A'
  ? <MapA />
  : <MapB />;

You can also create a map component generator function that accepts a hook, and returns a component to make it more DRY.
const createMapComponent = useHook => () => (
  const data = useHook();

  return <GoogleMap>{data}</GoogleMap>
);

const MapA = createMapComponent(useHookA);

const MapB = createMapComponent(useHookB);


I just see that you are writing bad React. You should not be running arbitrary code within the body of a component, which is going to affect the state of the component, without putting that logic inside a hook of some sort.
The code you currently have is equivalent to having a useEffect with an undefined dependency array, and this useEffect is changing the state, well of course you'll get frequent re-rendering!
See if the following reduces your rendering problems otherwise the other answer is pretty good:
const App = ( {modality} ) => {
   const dataA = useHookA();
   const dataB = useHookB();
   const data = useMemo(() => {
      switch (modality) {
         case 'A':
            return dataA;
         case 'B':
            return dataB;
         default:
            return undefined;
      }
   }, [modality]);

   return <GoogleMap>{data}</GoogleMap>
};

The dependency list for useMemo could also include dataA and dataB, if you expect them to change frequently and you want those changes to affect the state of the component. Otherwise, the list with just modality is fine.


I am having a hard time coming up with a good approach for splitting
business logic from a component. Due to different use cases,...

Ans:
It is ideal to constrain the use cases in a hook, such that it handles only a single use case. And let there be separate hooks handling each use case as you have tried initially. Please see the below quote from React docs in the same line.
“If your custom Hook API doesn’t constrain the use cases and is very
abstract, in the long run it’s likely to introduce more problems than
it solves.”
Citation : Keep your custom Hooks focused on concrete high-level use cases

I am going to overload the App. These hooks have functionality that is
causing frequent re-renders...

Ans:
As we know, rendering is only triggered when the states have been changed. Therefore an increase in the number of hooks in an app may not directly impact its performance by unnecessary renders. It is entirely based on the way the reactive changes have been coded. It is too obvious to have room to improve the codes passing flags just to cut the unnecessary renders. The bottom line is that rendering must be coded in its most natural way as a reaction to the interaction.

I cant think of a better way of doing this other than moving the hooks
one level above which i wanted to avoid because i wanted to keep map
logic within the map itself to avoid issues related to fetching google
api data. This needs review.

Ans:
Firstly, by extracting logic into a custom hook, the stateful logic is being shared. It means the same custom hook will become reusable in multiple places across the same component or in other components as well. Even If there is no immediate benefit or need for sharing some stateful logic, extracting logic into custom hooks, still makes the code more declarative. It would make code more expressive in its intent. It hides the gnarly details of any kind of implementation.
Secondly, even after extraction, a custom hook used in a component really remains as the body of the component. Unlike an event handler, a custom hook has access to the rendering life-cycle of a component. It receives the latest props, states and computed variables. An event handler on the other side, does not take part in the rendering process, it receives only a snapshot of the latest render and it remains so until the next render. Therefore it is quite remote to have issues in extracting custom hooks related with any kind of data fetch in the housing component.
Both points above have discussed here : Reusing Logic with Custom Hooks
Please see below a sample code based on the guidelines discussed above. As the custom hook modules cannot be imported in a dynamic way, the conditional has been coded in the respective hooks as it has been answered here :
Dynamic import of react hooks
App.js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const App = ({}) => {
  // the below state is used just for  interactivity by the buttons
  const [modality, setModality] = useState('A');

  const dataArray = [];
  dataArray[0] = useHookA(modality);
  dataArray[1] = useHookB(modality);

  // ...useHookC to useHookY go here

  dataArray[25] = useHookZ(modality);

  // a valid data will be there only in one of the array posistions
  const data = dataArray.filter((item) => item);

  function handleClick(modality) {
    //this stateSetter is called just to reset the display
    setModality(null);
    // this is the stateSetter for the new data, it has been made an async call,
    // just to avoid batching and bring in the desired display effect
    setTimeout(setModality(modality), 0);
  }
  return (
    <>
      data for Google Map : {data}
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('A')}>A Apply modality</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('B')}>B Apply modality</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => handleClick('X')}>X Apply modality</button>
      <br />
    </>
  );
};
export default App;

function useHookA(modality) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  if (modality == 'A') {
    // code the logic here during the initial render
    // code also the logic here after the data fetch
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (modality == 'A') {
      // any asyn data fetch here, now mocked by setTimeout
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setData('some data A'), 0);
      // clean up when the modality changes from A to some other
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    } else {
      // reset the state when the modality changes from non A modality to some other
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [modality]);
  return data;
}

function useHookB(modality) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  if (modality == 'B') {
    // code the logic here during the initial render
    // code also the logic here after the data fetch
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (modality == 'B') {
      // any asyn data fetch here, now mocked by setTimeout
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setData('some data B'), 0);
      // clean up when the modality changes from B to some other
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    } else {
      // reset the state when the modality changes from non B modality to some other
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [modality]);
  return data;
}

function useHookZ(modality) {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);
  if (modality == 'X') {
    // code the logic here during the initial render
    // code also the logic here after the data fetch
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if (modality == 'X') {
      // any asyn data fetch here, now mocked by setTimeout
      const timer = setTimeout(() => setData('some data X'), 0);
      // clean up when the modality changes from X to some other
      return () => {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      };
    } else {
      // reset the state when the modality changes from non X modality to some other
      setData(null);
    }
  }, [modality]);
  return data;
}

Test runs
On loading the app

On changing the modality from A to B

